# Vue: moving from slots to v-slot for Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I am currently using a simple implementation of slots in Vue 2.  I have my parent component using `MyComponent` and slotting in `OtherComponent`.  My `MyComponent` code
uses `<slot></slot>` for the content.  How would I make changes to the slots to adapt for Vue 3's `v-slot` since `slot` is deprecated?

**Parent.vue**

```
<MyComponent>
    <template v-slot="slotProps">
       <OtherComponent
          :data="slotProps.data"
       >
       </OtherComponent>
   </template>
</MyComponent>
```

**MyComponent.vue**

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
       <template v-for="(item, index) in data">
            <slot :item="item"></slot>
       </template>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: There are no changes needed in the code you posted. It's the `slot` **attribute** (and `slot-scope` attribute) that is deprecated for `v-slot`. `Parent.vue` is already using the newer syntax, so nothing needs to be migrated here.

Comment: excellent, thanks @tony19